# How to install/activate odoo9 enterprise on a community edititon

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, odoo-9

I already have an aws server running odoo9 community edition, but now i have also bought the enterprise edition (from settings within odoo). After the payment, we received an email with a link to the download section which is a .deb file for debian distribution. There is also a zipped file with the complete source.

In the past i usually installed odoo through the git repository, but there is no repository for the enterprise edition. And no documentation on installing it directly from the source files.

I am confused on how to install it, i have read some previous issues on github where users have just installed the enterprise addons. So is it like a complete different odoo and we need to install it on a separate instance or is it fine if i just install the additional addons on the community edition?

Comment: see this link :::: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/setup/install.html

Comment: Have u send your issue on odoo support guys ?

Comment: Yes i have sent an email to the support, and its been 5 days since my last email, and all they replied with was the link for the download page, again. For the price i paid for the enterprise, this kind of support is really really really bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it turns out that odoo enterprise is just a collection of some extra addons that extend the features of original addons.

The way i installed the enterprise edition is first i installed odoo 9 community, then i added another folder called enterprise-addons in the same directory as addons, and pasted all the enterprise addons in it. Then in the odoo configuration file (i.e. /etc/odoo-server.config) i added path to the new addons folder

```
addons_path=/odoo/odoo-server/enterprise-addons,/odoo/odoo-server/addons
```

The enterprise-addons should be added before the original addons, so it would first check enterprise-addons for any required addons and then check the addons folder.

**Now in order to make relevant changes to the database for the enterprise edition**, install the web module or if already installed then click on update, this will make all the necessary changes for the new enterprise edition.

**Checkout yenthe's answer** https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-install-odoo-version-9-enterprise-modules-94249

Answer (score 1):

you can run your odoo like that way:

First Go to your community edition location then run this commnad

```
./odoo.py -d test --db-filter=test --addons-path=../your Enterprice Path,/addons --without-demo=true
```

may be this is helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

So if u have Zip file of Enterprice version than replace  addons of community version with New one.

Please make Sure to Create Backuo nd upgrade modules after that